# c# read file descriptor from c pipe() function

Tags: c#, c, mono, pipe

I am creating a C pipe in C code using a function like this:

```
extern int *create_pipe() {
  int *_pipe = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
  pipe(_pipe);

  return _pipe;
}
```

I have a binding to this function in C# like this:

```
[DllImport("mydll")]
private static unsafe extern int *create_pipe();
```

I call the C# code like this:

```
unsafe {
  int *pipe = create_pipe();

  hostout = pipe[1];
  hostin = pipe[0];
}
```

I then try to create a `BinaryWriter` to the pipe like so:

```
var writer = new BinaryWriter(new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, new SafePipeHandle(new IntPtr(hostout), false)));
```

And I try to write a simple integer value to it:

```
writer.Write(50);
```

But I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: Invalid handle to path "[Unknown]"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (IntPtr handle, FileAccess access, Boolean ownsHandle, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean isAsync, Boolean isZeroSize) [0x0006a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:86 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (IntPtr handle, FileAccess access, Boolean ownsHandle, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean isAsync) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (intptr,System.IO.FileAccess,bool,int,bool)
  at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.get_Stream () [0x00021] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/PipeStream.cs:134 
  at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/PipeStream.cs:273 
  at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write (Int32 value) [0x0004b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/BinaryWriter.cs:244
```

Any ideas how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thank you in advance!